# How to get field API Name and Values from an array list to be iterated in the HTML

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, array, iteration

From the list below, I want to have column in html with FieldApiName(column1) and FieldValues(column2) in HTML.

How will I do that with the output list below. that accountIds can have different numbers of fieldApi and Values depending on what is get from a radio button in Javascript.

```
this.acccountList = [{"Id":"1234456788123","Age__c":"25","isActive":true},
{"Id":"0123456788123","Name":"Harry Potter","Age__c":"35","Birthyear__c":"1997"},
{"Id":"9865334534535","MobilePhone":"1234567","isCallCenter__c":"true"}]
```

Desired output in HTML:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map the values into an array, which you can then render as HTML. Here's an example script:

```
let data = [{"Id":"1234456788123","Age__c":"25","isActive":true},{"Id":"0123456788123","Name":"Harry Potter","Age__c":"35","Birthyear__c":"1997"},{"Id":"9865334534535","MobilePhone":"1234567","isCallCenter__c":"true"}];
this.accountlist = data.map((record) => ({
  key: record.Id,
  values: Object.entries(record).map(([field, value]) => ({ field, value })),
}));
```

Basically, we're changing the data into:

```
[
  {
    "key": "1234456788123",
    "values": [
      { "field": "Id", "value": "1234456788123" },
      { "field": "Age__c", "value": "25" },
      { "field": "isActive", "value": true }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "0123456788123",
    "values": [
      { "field": "Id", "value": "0123456788123" },
      { "field": "Name", "value": "Harry Potter" },
      { "field": "Age__c", "value": "35" },
      { "field": "Birthyear__c", "value": "1997" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "9865334534535",
    "values": [
      { "field": "Id", "value": "9865334534535" },
      { "field": "MobilePhone", "value": "1234567" },
      { "field": "isCallCenter__c", "value": "true" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which you then render in your HTML as:

```
<template for:each={accountlist} for:item="account">
  <tr key={account.key}>
    <template for:each={account.values} for:item="fieldValue">
      <td>{fieldValue.field}</td>
      <td>{fieldValue.value}</td>
    </template>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: Great that totally makes sense. It works. Thank you for your help